# Transit in Bangkok with a different air ticket

Tags: transit, thailand, bangladeshi-citizens, bkk

I'm a Bangladeshi citizen working for the UN, traveling from South Sudan to Bangkok with Ethiopian Airlines and taking another international flight with Biman Bangladesh Airlines on the same day three hours later from Bangkok to Dhaka, but the two tickets are booked separately.

How should I collect my luggage from Bangkok airport and drop it for the Bangkok Dhaka flight? Do I have to clear immigration first in Bangkok, then collect my luggage from the belt and then check in for the Bangkok-Dhaka flight, or there is an easier way? I don't have a Thailand visa.

Comment: Do you have a diplomatic passport?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you need a visa.**  You will need to go through immigration & customs to collect your luggage and check it in again, and to do so you need a visa for Thailand.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. So if I don't give a check in luggage, I don't need a Visa right? In that case, can I collect the boarding pass of Biman Bangladesh Airlines if I am unable to get by on line check- In, remaining in transit area without Visa?

Comment: Yes, you don't need a transit visa if your connection is less than 12 hours: https://travelezy.net.au/thailand-transit-visa/ (not an official source, mind you)